# Socket.RemoteEndPoint returns gateway address

Tags: c#, sockets

For some reason the C# socket.RemoteEndPoint started returning the address of the default gateway. It used to work and I know the code hasn't changed. I'm not sure when it started occurring as the logs don't go back far enough so I'm not sure what could have happened to this server to cause this. Everything seems to be working normally. Just not getting the remote IP anymore.

Anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Here is the relevant code.

```
    public void startClientListening(string ipString, int port)
    {

                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);

                // Create the listening socket...
                clientListenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
                // Bind to local IP Address...
                clientListenerSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
                // Start listening...
                clientListenerSocket.Listen(32);
                // Create the call back for any client connections...
                clientListenerSocket.BeginAccept(onClientConnect, clientListenerSocket);
    }

    private void onClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
            Socket workerSocket = clientListenerSocket.EndAccept(asyn);
            workerSocket.NoDelay = true;

            //This returns 192.168.1.1 rather than the remoteIp
            string remoteIp = ((IPEndPoint)workerSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: I don't know that it's the cause of  your problem, but you should get rid of those try/catch blocks - they're preventing you from finding out what's wrong.

Comment: The code is largely trimmed down. I just pulled out the relevant socket code.

Comment: Trimmed down or not, get rid of those try/catch blocks. And you should get rid of them in the real code, too.

Comment: There is handling and logging for the exception in the real code... I dont see how the code could be doing it, it was working, then it wasnt. I'm wondering if router/firewall .net framework update could possibly cause this.

Comment: is your client machine able to ping or tracert the server / listener?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the default gateway was a router/ip firewall before but now it is a proxy/application firewall.

In this case the ip connection is instantiated by the proxy and therefore you see the ip address of the proxy and not of the real client.